# How to remove the windows 7 bootloader from my OEM partition?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, bootloader, oem

I have a laptop with an OEM partition containing the files for a recovery of Windows XP. In the past I've used this OEM partition by setting it active and let the computer boot it. It would automatically start its recovery procedure.

**What I've done to end up in the situation that I have now:**
I have deleted all partitions on the harddrive except the OEM partition. I installed Windows 7 to this harddrive, which worked perfectly, however, since the OEM partition was active it has installed its bootloader to this partition. (Windows 7 seems to install it's bootloader on another partition when it gets the chance). Since I didn't want to bootloader to be on the OEM partition I have made a partion other than the OEM partition active and again deleted all partitions except the OEM partition. Then I reinstalled windows 7 and it has created a seperate partition for it's bootloader.

So now I have the Windows 7 partition, a 100MB partition created by the Windows installer containing it's bootloader, and the OEM partition. However the OEM partition still contains the previous bootloader which no serves no purpose any more. In fact, if I now turn the OEM partion active it will start that bootloader rather than initiate the OEM recovery procedure. How can I remove this Windows 7 bootloader from the OEM partition and restore the OEM partition's recovery procedure?

Answer (score 1):

[Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net) is the answer.

Visual BCD Editor is a complete Windows BCD GUI not just a partial implementation of BCD interface as other GUI tools are.

**To delete any loader from BCD:**

Run Visual BCD Editor.
On the left side all loaders in BCD are listed.

Select loader to be deleted by clicking on loader, then right click and select "Delete Object".

You can open any BCD store not just the system store (\Boot\BCD) and manipulate it.

**To repair Windows XP booting:**

1. Write NT5 (Windows XP) boot record to partition in question. 
   (You can map it temporarely to say Z:). Then select in Visual BCD Editor - Menu->Repair->Repair Boot Records - select "Drive" and "XP/older", confirm.
2. Examine that on partition in question the files ntldr, ntdetect.com and boot.ini are still present. The files should be there if they have not been deleted (these files are not overwriten by Windows 7 installation).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) should solve your problem.

> **Take control of your boot loader.**
>
> EasyBCD supercharges your Windows PC, allowing you to dual-boot to
> your heart's content.
>
> Also boot into legacy systems Microsoft doesn't support: MS-DOS, Windows 9x, Windows ME, and Windows 2000!

Comment: Just tried this, following your advice. However it only sees one bootloader, the one being on the 100MB partition created by the windows installer. The OEM partition seems invisible to the software. Any advice?